# Changing the default windows manager in xfce

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, xubuntu, compiz

I'm running a copy of xubuntu with xfce as my desktop environment and compiz ad my windows manager. I'd like to make compiz the default over xfwm4, but I'm having trouble locating the configuration to do this.

Right now I'm running `compiz --replace` on login but I'd prefer to have it be the default so it doesn't have to start up xfwm4 before replacing.

Where can I find the configuration to make compiz(or any other windows manager) the default?

Comment: Did you try methods on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz#XFCE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you kill xfwm and start compiz and have just the minimum system set up and working. Then you should be able to log out, and be sure to check the box "save session for future logins". Then when you log in again the compiz should be running. Alternatively, you can go to the "Session and Startup" from Settings, and select "Session" tab, then click the "Save Session" button.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are looking for is located at: ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml

There you should change xfwm4 to compiz.